# JPQL SQL make a query base on a list of arguments

Tags: java, sql, jpql

I have a class Person as followed

```
public class Person{
   String name;
   //----------
}
```

I would like to query the list of persons where name are like "name1" and name like "name2", and name like "name3" ....
so, i would like to have a funtion like this

```
public void queryPersonsWhithNameLike(List<String>  names){
   //here is my query
   String queryStr = "select p from Person p where p.name LIKE :names.get(0) AND p.name LIKE :names.get(1) AND p.name LIKE :names.ger(2) AND......";

}
```

Please how can i write a such query using sql and jpql?

Comment: Devide the query by parts and add each part separately or construct another query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

public void queryPersonsWhithNameLike(List  names){
Iterate over the List and construct a query:

```
String queryStr = "select p from Person p";
int count=0;
for(String str:names) {
   if(count==0) queryStr+="WHERE p.name LIKE :name"+count;
   else queryStr+=" AND p.name LIKE :name"+count;
   count++;
}
... Initialize query
for(String str:names) {
... Set all the :name+count as parameters
}
```